# Calling an object in constructor in other method/function

Tags: java

I am newbie in java got stuck in one situation where i have an excel object in my constructor and i have to call that object in my function/method.
my code looks like

```
public class Hotel {

Hotel() throws BiffException, IOException {

    FileInputStream configurationExcel=new FileInputStream("C://Users//Rashmi//Desktop//TravalPS_RegregrestionTest1.xls");
    Workbook book = Workbook.getWorkbook(configurationExcel);
    Sheet firstsheet= book.getSheet(0);     
}
public void test(){
        Cell excelcell= firstsheet.getCell(2, 2);//this line is throwing error
}
```

i want to use first-sheet object in the test function ,how can i achieve that,

Comment: the word is "newbie", not "new bee".

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Constructor creates multiple variables, how to return them through other methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840480/constructor-creates-multiple-variables-how-to-return-them-through-other-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to assign `firstSheet` to a member variable of the class so that it is accessible in other methods:

```
public class Hotel {
    /** Variables defined here are accessible in the entire class */
    private Sheet mFirstSheet;

    Hotel() throws BiffException, IOException {
        /* Variables defined here are only accessible within these curly braces */

        FileInputStream configurationExcel = new FileInputStream("...");
        Workbook book = Workbook.getWorkbook(configurationExcel);
        mFirstSheet = book.getSheet(0);
    }

    public void test() {
        Cell excelcell = mFirstSheet.getCell(2, 2);
    }
}
```

Note the difference between *definition* and *initialisation*. `mFirstSheet` is *defined* in the body of the class (within the class's curly braces), but it is *initialised* in the constructor. It is where the variable is defined that determines where it is accessible from.

Another point on accessibility, your class is defined as **public**, but your constructor (`Hotel() ...`) has no modifiers on it. In Java, this makes it **package private** by default (meaning that only other classes in the same package, or if there is no package, same directory, see this constructor). This means that while classes in other packages see the class, they can't make new versions of it. This may be your intention, and there are certain uses for this, but I'm guessing that it's not, so you probably want to make your constructor public too: `public Hotel() ...`

#### A note on scoping, and accessibility

With this new found knowledge on scoping, it may be tempting to make it so that everything is accessible everywhere, #justincase. Don't do this. Here's why:

- It pollutes namespaces

  Suppose you have several methods that take a cell from the sheet, but you defined your `excelcell` variable to be a private field in your class (in the same place as `mFirstSheet`). Now all the methods that were interacting with previously completely different cells, are all storing them in the same variable. This is now an extra headache for you, making sure that the method properly initialises `excelcell` before using it, or else it will get some other method's cell, so this variable should stay scoped to each method it is used in.
- It leaves long living references lying around

  Java is **garbage collected**, this means, when memory is running low, there is a system called the *garbage collector* that looks for objects that no longer have any references attached to them, and frees the memory associated with them. Once you leave the scope of a method, variables defined there are no longer reachable, so the garbage collector can get rid of them, if no other references to them exist). But, if you assigned all the variables as private fields of the class, then they would exist atleast as long as the instance of the class does (because the instance now holds a reference to the object).

  A good example of an object this would happen to is your `configurationExcel` variable. As it stands, it is *most likely* garbage collected once you leave the constructor. Which is good, because it holds a file pointer that you don't really want to leave open longer than necessary (It is possible that `book` holds a reference to it, but I'm guessing due to its purpose that it probably doesn't). If however, it were a private field, it would live as long as the instance of the class, all the time going unused, its memory wasted.
- It breaks **encapsulation**

  This is not always true, except in the case of making private fields public. You'll notice that when I defined `mFirstSheet`, I made it a `private Sheet`. This means that it is only accessible to this class itself (and its inner classes and static contexts). If you were to define it as `public Sheet mFirstSheet`, then it would be accessible to anything and everything, which may seem like a good idea to begin with, because it saves you having to write a getter to let other parts of your program access it, **but it is not a good idea**. It means you have no control as to what happens to the internal state of your class, anything could replace it:

  ```
  public class ChaosMonkey() {
      public static void wreakHavoc(Hotel hotel) {
          hotel.mFirstSheet = null;
          /** Havoc wreaked */
      }
  }
  ```

  And you wouldn't know when or why or how.

  (You may be thinking at this point: What if I *do* want other classes to be able to modify `mFirstSheet`. If it is part of the design of your class that other classes should be able to change its internal state without any sort of restriction, then this is a bad design, and is indicative of the fact that the field in question doesn't belong in that class).

Comment: @user2181194 a word of advice: don't just look at the solution,  read the rest of the answer, it'll help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`firstsheet` is not a field, but a local variable in the contructor so you cannot reach it in `test()` method.

```
public class Hotel {

private FileInputStream configurationExcel;
private Sheet firstsheet;
private Workbook book;

public Hotel() throws BiffException, IOException {

    this.configurationExcel=new FileInputStream("C://Users//Rashmi//Desktop//TravalPS_RegregrestionTest1.xls");
    this.book = Workbook.getWorkbook(configurationExcel);
    this.firstsheet= book.getSheet(0);     
}
public void test(){
        Cell excelcell= this.firstsheet.getCell(2, 2);//this line is throwing error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. There are two types of variables.
 Member Variables and Local Variables.

Member Variables are part of the class and declared for the class. 
Something like this

```
public class Hotel {

**private String hotelName;**

protected void bookHotel(){
this.hotelName = "Something";
.....
}
}
```

In member variables, you have visibility to the variable within the methods of the class.

Local variables are initialized or used within a function. One example of that would be the variable that you use in the **For** loop.

```
public class Hotel {

**private String hotelName;**

protected void bookHotel(){

**String myHotelName = "Marriott";**
this.hotelName = myHotelName;
.....
}
}
```

Here myHotelName is a local variable and wouldnt be accessible in another method.

**Now, in your case, firstSheet isnt a member variable, but a local variable. Hence, it isnt accessible in another method. To use it, if you do need to use it, it has to be a member variable of the class.**

Answer (score 1):

The object firstsheet does only exist in the scope of the constructor function. You have to declare it as a global field if you want to use it in other methods. Here is an example:

```
public class Hotel {
  private Sheet firstsheet; // firstsheet is a global field

  // Constructor
  public Hotel() throws BiffException, IOException {
    FileInputStream configurationExcel=new FileInputStream("C://Users//Rashmi//Desktop//TravalPS_RegregrestionTest1.xls");
    Workbook book = Workbook.getWorkbook(configurationExcel);
    firstsheet= book.getSheet(0); // firstsheet get's a value     
  }

  // Some method
  public void test(){
    Cell excelcell = firstsheet.getCell(2, 2); // firstsheet also exists in this scope now
  }
}
```